# Display a banner if custom field is true

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I got the following code to display banner over any repro:

```
<div>           
<div id="publicidad-video">
<IFRAME FRAMEBORDER="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="NO" WIDTH="300"      HEIGHT="250" SRC="su publicidad"></IFRAME>
<br>
<div style="float: left; left: 180px; position: relative; top: -210px; z-index: 9999;">
<span class="jbtn" onmouseover="jQuery(this).hide('fast');jQuery('#asd1').show('slow')">cerrar</span>
</div>
<div id="asd1" style="display: none; float: left; position: relative; top: -65px; z-index: 9999;">
<span class="jbtn" onclick="jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();">cerrar</span>
</div>
</div>  
<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("video"); echo $values[0]; ?>
</div>
```

I got the custom field call video, so I need display the ad banner only IF the post got a video, because if I use like that the ad banner will be appear in all posts with videos or not.

Anybody please can tell me what code I need to add?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The code that you're using will generate an array with all posts that have the custom value of video. If you wanted to check if the current post has a value in the custom field 'video' then use:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "video", true)) : ?>

<!-- HTML here if post has a video -->

<?php endif; ?>
```